# Find specific string in a text file with VBS script

Tags: text, vbscript, substring

I need to find the string "Test Case " &  index in a txt file.

I give you an example of the lines you can find in this file:

```
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1A1">Log_ in_U1A1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
```

As you can see in the second line I have an occurrence of the string "Test Case".

What I want to do is to add another particular string in the line which preceeds the one where "Test Case 5" appears. For example:

```
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1A1">Log_ in_U1A1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Logs/DD/Beginning_of_DD_TC5.html">Beginning_of_DD_TC5</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
```

It's also important that the line I add has an index i which depends on the Test Case number, and i need to add it before the first occurrence of "Test Case" & i, i dont care about the following occurrences.

I tested if InStr function worked with an example:

```
Dim objFSO, filepath, objInputFile, tmpStr, substrToFind
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filepath = "C:\VBS\filediprova.txt"
substrToFind = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../Test case 5"
Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filepath)
tmpStr = objInputFile.ReadLine
If InStr(tmpStr, substrToFind) <= 0 Then
   WScript.Echo "No matches"
Else
   WScript.Echo "Found match"
End If
```

And it works, it recognizes my substring. In this small example the txt file only contans the followingline:

```
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
```

Now, when I try to loop over a file with much more lines I have some problem, I use the same InStr function.
I wrote the following loop:

```
Do until objInputFile.AtEndOfStream
   strToAdd = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../../Logs/DD/Beginning_of_DD_TC" & CStr(index) & ".html" & chr(34) & ">Beginning_of_DD_TC" & CStr(index) & "</a></td></tr>"
   substrToFind = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../Test case " & index
   firstStr = "<?xml version" 'my file always starts like this
   tmpStr = objInputFile.ReadLine
   If InStr(tmpStr, substrToFind) <= 0 Then
       If Instr(tmpStr, firstStr) > 0 Then
          text = tmpStr 'to avoid the first empty line
       Else
          text = text & vbCrLf & tmpStr
       End If
   Else
      text = text & vbCrLf & strToAdd & vbCrLf & tmpStr
      index = index + 1
   End If
Loop
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend using a regular expressions instead of string operations for this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = "C:\VBS\filediprova.txt"

newtext = vbLf & "<tr><td><a href=""..."">Beginning_of_DD_TC5</a></td></tr>"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(\n.*?Test Case \d)"
re.Global  = False
re.IgnoreCase = True

text = f.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll
f.OpenTextFile(filename, 2).Write re.Replace(text, newText & "$1")
```

The regular expression will match a line feed (`\n`) followed by a line containing the string `Test Case` followed by a number (`\d`), and the replacement will prepend that with the text you want to insert (variable `newtext`). Setting `re.Global = False` makes the replacement stop after the first match.

If the line breaks in your text file are encoded as `CR-LF` (carriage return + line feed) you'll have to change `\n` into `\r\n` and `vbLf` into `vbCrLf`.

If you have to modify several text files, you could do it in a loop like this:

```
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\VBS").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "txt" Then
    text = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll
    f.OpenAsTextStream(2).Write re.Replace(text, newText & "$1")
  End If
Next
```

Comment: I was also thinking about using reg expressions, but I didn't know where to start from, they seem like aramaic to me! Even though I know java and visual basic I never dared using them. I'll keep in consideration this possibility, but can you give me a good link for a tutorial (for dummies) about regex?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/939/An-Introduction-to-Regular-Expressions), and of course the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2).

Answer (score 5):

Wow, after few attempts I finally figured out how to deal with my text edits in vbs. The code works perfectly, it gives me the result I was expecting. Maybe it's not the best way to do this, but it does its job.
Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim StdIn:  Set StdIn = WScript.StdIn
Dim StdOut: Set StdOut = WScript


Main()

Sub Main()

Dim objFSO, filepath, objInputFile, tmpStr, ForWriting, ForReading, count, text, objOutputFile, index, TSGlobalPath, foundFirstMatch
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
TSGlobalPath = "C:\VBS\TestSuiteGlobal\Test suite Dispatch Decimal - Global.txt"
ForReading = 1
ForWriting = 2
Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(TSGlobalPath, ForReading, False)
count = 7
text=""
foundFirstMatch = false

Do until objInputFile.AtEndOfStream
    tmpStr = objInputFile.ReadLine
    If foundStrMatch(tmpStr)=true Then
        If foundFirstMatch = false Then
            index = getIndex(tmpStr)
            foundFirstMatch = true
            text = text & vbCrLf & textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,"true")
        End If
        If index = getIndex(tmpStr) Then
            text = text & vbCrLf & textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,"false")
        ElseIf index < getIndex(tmpStr) Then
            index = getIndex(tmpStr)
            text = text & vbCrLf & textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,"true")
        End If
    Else
        text = text & vbCrLf & textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,"false")
    End If
Loop
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\VBS\NuovaProva.txt", ForWriting, true)
objOutputFile.Write(text)
End Sub


Function textSubstitution(tmpStr,index,foundMatch)
Dim strToAdd
strToAdd = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../../Logs/CF5.0_Features/Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC" & CStr(index) & ".html" & chr(34) & ">Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC" & CStr(index) & "</a></td></tr>"
If foundMatch = "false" Then
    textSubstitution = tmpStr
ElseIf foundMatch = "true" Then
    textSubstitution = strToAdd & vbCrLf & tmpStr
End If
End Function


Function getIndex(tmpStr)
Dim substrToFind, charAtPos, char1, char2
substrToFind = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../Test case "
charAtPos = len(substrToFind) + 1
char1 = Mid(tmpStr, charAtPos, 1)
char2 = Mid(tmpStr, charAtPos+1, 1)
If IsNumeric(char2) Then
    getIndex = CInt(char1 & char2)
Else
    getIndex = CInt(char1)
End If
End Function

Function foundStrMatch(tmpStr)
Dim substrToFind
substrToFind = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../Test case "
If InStr(tmpStr, substrToFind) > 0 Then
    foundStrMatch = true
Else
    foundStrMatch = false
End If
End Function
```

This is the original txt file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
  <title>Test Suite</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium"><tbody>
<tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/TC_Environment_setting">TC_Environment_setting</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/TC_Set_variables">TC_Set_variables</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/TC_Set_ID">TC_Set_ID</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_in_Admin">Log_in_Admin</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Set_Roles_Dispatch_Decimal">Set_Roles_Dispatch_Decimal</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1A1">Log_ in_U1A1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/contrD1">contrD1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1B1">Log_ in_U1B1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Search&OpenApp">Search&OpenApp</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/FormEND">FormEND</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Controllo END">Controllo END</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1A1">Log_ in_U1A1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 6 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 6 DD/contrD1">contrD1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1B1">Log_ in_U1B1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Search&OpenApp">Search&OpenApp</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/FormEND">FormEND</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Controllo END">Controllo END</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1A1">Log_ in_U1A1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 7 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Controllo DeadLetter">Controllo DeadLetter</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Set_Roles_Dispatch_Decimal">Set_Roles_Dispatch_Decimal</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout_BAC">Logout_BAC</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the result I'm expecting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
  <title>Test Suite</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium"><tbody>
<tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/TC_Environment_setting">TC_Environment_setting</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/TC_Set_variables">TC_Set_variables</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/TC_Set_ID">TC_Set_ID</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_in_Admin">Log_in_Admin</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Set_Roles_Dispatch_Decimal">Set_Roles_Dispatch_Decimal</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1A1">Log_ in_U1A1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Logs/CF5.0_Features/Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC5.html">Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC5</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/contrD1">contrD1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1B1">Log_ in_U1B1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Search&OpenApp">Search&OpenApp</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 5 DD/FormEND">FormEND</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Controllo END">Controllo END</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1A1">Log_ in_U1A1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Logs/CF5.0_Features/Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC6.html">Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC6</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 6 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 6 DD/contrD1">contrD1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1B1">Log_ in_U1B1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Search&OpenApp">Search&OpenApp</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Controllo END">Controllo END</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Log_ in_U1A1">Log_ in_U1A1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Logs/CF5.0_Features/Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC7.html">Beginning_of_CF5.0_Features_TC7</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../Test case 7 DD/Form1">Form1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Controllo DeadLetter">Controllo DeadLetter</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout">Logout</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Component/Set_Roles_Dispatch_Decimal">Set_Roles_Dispatch_Decimal</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="../../Login/Logout_BAC">Logout_BAC</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change like this ..

```
firstStr = "<?xml version" 'my file always starts like this

Do until objInputFile.AtEndOfStream  

    strToAdd = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../../Logs/DD/Beginning_of_DD_TC" & CStr(index) & ".html" & chr(34) & ">Beginning_of_DD_TC" & CStr(index) & "</a></td></tr>"  

   substrToFind = "<tr><td><a href=" & chr(34) & "../Test case " & trim(cstr((index)))

   tmpStr = objInputFile.ReadLine

   If InStr(tmpStr, substrToFind) <= 0 Then
       If Instr(tmpStr, firstStr) > 0 Then
          text = tmpStr 'to avoid the first empty line
       Else
          text = text & vbCrLf & tmpStr
       End If
   Else
      text = text & vbCrLf & strToAdd & vbCrLf & tmpStr

   End If
   index = index + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Hello matzone, thank you for making me realize how dumb I was!! I didn't realize I forgot to write CInt(index). I'll check if the script will work with this modification and let you know.

Comment: In truth the correct modification was CStr(index), I checked if it works like this, but it doesn't. There might be some other reason why...

Comment: Maybe the problem is the loop

Comment: Dim index As Integer
Integer is then used to create the string with CStr(index)